# What are quadratic patches in Livne et al 2019's paper on convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

As I was trying to make sense of this paper, I came to learn about the term `quadratic patches` in [Livne *et al* 2019](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnins.2019.00097/full#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20these%20problems%20we%20extracted%201%2C000%20quadratic%20patches%20per%20patient). This is a fairly new term to me.

Could anyone explain or redirect to some tutorials?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question to ask (+1), but it might be challenging to answer. The term is only used once in the entire paper, and the only relevant hits on Google are the same paper, or papers written by the same people. You might have to email the authors to learn more.

Comment: @Sycorax I couldn't find their email in the link/paper. So asked the same question in the GitHub repo as an issue. I will post here if they explain. Thanks.

Comment: Googling does reveal quite a few articles about "quadratic patches", which appear to be a topic of interest in computational neuroscience (rather than ML/stats per se). Here's a pretty neat article: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1077314296905019?token=56F8B193BDC3BCB3FFD22231B1611A7F89D02374E930A8109B2DDDB2BADADEC4AEAAB7B26339F20375562041D7AC90BA&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20221220161403